# change left navigation button text

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios8.1

need help to change the text for the left navigation button in ios8

tried

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Text" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

and

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Text"      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> need help to change the text for the left navigation button

That's very confused, because the left navigation button and the back button are two completely different things. So you *say* "left navigation button" but then what you *set* is the back button. Thus it's impossible to be sure what you're really trying to do. And moreover, the left button and the back button conflict with one another - by default, they will not both appear. So you have to be careful about that too.

I'm going to assume, in this answer, that although you *say* the left navigation button, you don't mean it - you mean the back button. And that the top view controller has no left button.

Assuming that's the case, the thing to keep in mind here is that when the back button is showing, it is not the current view controller's navigation item whose back button this is, but the view controller below it in the stack. That is, the back button belongs the back item's navigation item.

Thus, that is the view controller that needs to modify its navigation item's back item, and it needs to do it *before* another view controller gets pushed onto the stack - preferably much earlier, in its own `viewDidLoad`.

Thus, this code (from my book) will work if run in the `viewDidLoad` *of the correct view controller*:

```
UIBarButtonItem* b =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go Back"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = b;
```

But of course if you mean the left bar button item after all, then forget all that. If you mean the left bar button item, then the problem is not that you've got the wrong view controller but that you've got the wrong bar button item!

Comment: Here's a downloadable example project that demonstrates: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/ca886a10d17817388f5ff26a042bfc94a37f1d1b/bk2ch06p281navigationInterface/ch19p615navigationInterface

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIButton *buttonLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLeftAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 20)];
    [buttonLeft setTitle:@"YourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:buttonLeft];
```

Try above code.